# Rotated surface code vs unrotated surface code - Boundary stabilizers

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code, surface-code

I use these image for the questions below:

[image]

[image]

When we look at the surface code, we can define it in two slightly different ways.

The first figure shows a way where we keep all the data qubits and ancilla qubits inside the black region. The second figure shows a way where we keep all the data qubits and ancilla qubits inside the orange region. The boundaries of Figure 1 have 2-qubit stabilizers while the boundaries of Figure 2 have 3-qubit stabilizers.

**Question 1:** For the surface code in Figure 1, why do we drop the stabilizers in yellow circles? How did we know to drop those but keep the other stabilizers?

For example, looking at data qubits $Da$ and $Db$, the $Z$ stabilizer that connects them is dropped along with the other data qubits it used to connect to. On the other hand, looking at $Db$ and $Dc$, the $X$ stabilizer that connects them is retained.

What is the rationale behind which boundary stabilizers to keep and which ones to discard?

**Question 2:** What happens to the surface code of Figure 1 if I add those additional stabilizers circled in yellow? Since I add one data qubit and one stabilizer each time, do I just get the same encoded state as before?